# SMB share from ubuntu 14.04 is not available to Windows 10

Tags: linux, samba, windows-10

This is a virtualbox vm, ubuntu guest on a windows host, bridged (ip 192.168.1.236). My home windows lan is HOUSE. `ps aux | grep smbd` shows me that smbd is running. I have restarted it after adding/changing the config. The vm is pingable from Windows.

But when I send Windows to `\\srvr1\nodeprojs` it times out.

I've done this before (it's been a while) so I know I had it working. I'm just not sure exactly what I did. It was nowhere near the pain that it's being this time. IIRC, previously it took me the matter of a guide plus a few minutes.

my smb.conf

```
[global]
workgroup = HOUSE
server string = Samba Server %v
netbios name = srvr1
security = user
map to guest = bad user
name resolve order = bcast host
dns proxy = no

[nodeprojs]
path = /~/nodeprojs
browsable = yes
writable = yes
guest ok = yes
read only = no
```

Answer (score 0):

In the past, the guest was apparently ip `10.10.10.10` while the rest of my lan is `192.168.*.*`. I know that was the ip because I'd mapped a windows drive letter to the smb share at that ip. Since I have no recollection of configuring gateways or routing tables, I can't imagine how I made that ip work.

So I changed the guest from NAT to Bridged Network and bounced the guest dhcp to give the interface a bridged ip. Once I did that, and could ping it from windows (duh), then the smb share was available at `//192.168.1.232`.

I have a bunch of conveniences in the conf. I mean it's a local VM for a dev environment. However insecure it might be, I care MUCH more about the [principle of least astonishment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment) and Getting Things Done.

For posterity, here's the `smb.conf`

```
[global]
   workgroup = WORKGROUP
   server string = %h server (Samba, Ubuntu)
   dns proxy = no
   log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
   max log size = 1000
   syslog = 0
   panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d
   server role = standalone server
   passdb backend = tdbsam
   obey pam restrictions = yes
   unix password sync = yes
   passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
   passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .
   pam password change = yes
   map to guest = bad user
   usershare allow guests = yes
[homes]
   comment = Home Directories
   read only = no
   create mask = 0755
   directory mask = 0755
   valid users = %S
[primary]
   force user = vagrant
   comment = VagrantShare
   path = /home/vagrant
   writeable = yes
   ;valid users = @vagrant
   guest ok = yes
   read only = no
   create mask = 0777
```